# rename rows in datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqldatareader

I currently am working with a database for a 3rd party application that has no form checks for data in the columns I am working with. I am using `SqlDataReader` (because this does not need to modify the existing tables in the database) to put the data into a datatable and removing duplicates, but when I remove duplicates I am still left with garbage duplicates through different people entering the data incorrectly. For example;

- Apple
- APPL
- Banana
- BANNEAN
- BANA
- oRang
- etc...

How can I correct them in the datatable so the datatable only has Apple, Orange, etc...

Fortunately there are only a few different items that go into this column, and all start with a different string for example cen, cas, so if I was able to change all beginning with app

Unfortunately modifying the original program to have the data checked on entry is not an option.

Comment: That sucks that you can not just modify the checks in the original `SRC` you would have to somehow assume what the user meant perhaps you could add some `Extension` Method or `Interface that would force the user to validate there entry if the word they entered is not a correct word.. this is a good question does this possibly do what you are looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141809.aspx

Comment: @DJKRAZE Unfortunately the 3rd party application for data-entry is completely closed, but the tables can be directly accessed. I am using the tables from the application database, as well as tables from another application to generate custom reports above the functionality of both of the original applications. The problem is with with out form checking on that field people put whatever is close or whatever acronym they think up for the item. If I can essentiall form check the datatable(s) then I should be good to go.

Comment: sounds like you need to have some tighter `Standards` put into place this has to be such a mess how does one even manage Inventory or Profit /Loss Margins with something like that .. sounds like this is not a `"US based Operation"`

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am working with alot of historical data to build profiles. I am writing an application that will pull that data from that database, convert it, and display it in a grid view based on conditions set by the user. Current and future data is and will be ok. It is only two fields that I assume the original Dev intended to be Dynamic due to their nature.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I think this script will help you.

```
update [TableName]
set [ColumnName] = 'someName'
where [ColumnName] in 
(
select [ColumnName] from [TableName]
where [ColumnName] != 'someName'
and [ColumnName] != 'someName'
and [ColumnName] != 'someName'
and [ColumnName] != 'someName'
and [ColumnName] != 'someName'
)
--to be safe google "begin transaction" and how to "rollback" the changes
```

after changing the name of the column you can delete the column based on the name you've changed it to.

```
delete [TableName]
where [ColumnName] = 'TheName'
```

Comment: Is it not possible to modify the datatable pulled from the database?

Comment: sure, you can modify it and display what ever you want to display out of that table to the user.

Comment: Do you have an easy solution to do that? I can remove duplicates, but before I do that I want to rename garbage duplicates. Do you know how to do that?